# Checkbutton responds to clicks on text

Tags: python, tkinter

By default, tkinter's `Checkbutton` widget responds to clicks anywhere in the widget, rather than just in the check box field.

For example, consider the following (Python 2) code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
main = tk.Tk()
check = tk.Checkbutton(main, text="Click").pack()
main.mainloop()
```

Running this code results in a small window, with a single check box, accompanied by the word "Click". If you click on the check box, it is toggled.

However, this also happens if you click on the *text* of the widget, rather than the check box.

Is this preventable? I could make a *separate* widget to hold the text, but that still results in a small area around the check box that responds to clicks.

Comment: why do you want to make it harder for the user to check the checkbutton?

Comment: @BryanOakley: I want to make it harder for the user to *accidentally* check the checkbutton. :)

Comment: Are you certain that's a real problem?

Comment: Quite. I have a screen where the user is to set a whole bunch of options. In fact, more than fir on screen, so the user can scroll. But to scroll the screen, it needs to have focus (just like how I can't scroll this web page without my browser being the active screen) which it gets by the user clicking on it. The user clicking on an innocent-seeming area (plain text) but a check box being toggled because of it has caused accidents several times in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions come to mind:

1. Do as you suggest and create a separate widget for the checkbutton and for the label.
2. replace the bindings on the checkbutton with your own, and examine the x/y coordinates of the click and only accept the click if it happens in a small region of the widget.

Answer (score 0):

This program creates a checkbutton and overrides the default event on it by binding a method to the checkbutton. When the button is clicked, the method checks a defined limit to allow the normal operation or to override. OP wanted to make sure that when text of the checkbutton is clicked, no default action is taken. That is essentially what this does.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        self.checkvar = IntVar()
        check = tk.Checkbutton(parent, text='Click', variable=self.checkvar)
        check.bind('<Button-1>', self.checkCheck)
        check.pack()
        print(dir(check))

    def checkCheck(self, event):
        # Set limit based on your font and preference
        limit = 18
        print(event.x, event.y, self.checkvar.get())
        if event.x > limit or event.y > limit:
            self.checkvar.set(not self.checkvar.get())
        else:
            print("Normal behavior")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = tk.Tk()
    app = App(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you have the lines 
`import tkinter.ttk as ttk` and 
`from tkinter import *` ?

Comment: I presume 18 is the width/height of a checkbox on your computer? Is there any way to get the boundaries of the box programmatically?

Comment: Cut and paste into an existing program -- my fault @Nae.

Comment: @acdr, You're correct, the 18 is the arbitrary size (boundary of acceptance) for the click. You can set it (or even add another for x vs y limits) to what works best in your application.

Comment: @RonNorris I'd lose them if they're unrelated. Also this would be a much better answer if it explained what the code does.